# Pass variable from class into admin-on-rest datagrid

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, admin-on-rest

I'm displaying a users list from an api using admin-on-rest.  I can't figure out how to pass a variable from the class in `src/Progress.js` to the datagrid component in `src/Users.js`

Here is `Users.js`. I've included the whole file because I may be missing something very basic as I'm new to working with React:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Line } from 'rc-progress';
import {Datagrid,Edit,EmailField,Filter,FunctionField,List,ReferenceField,SimpleShowLayout,Show,TextField,TextInput } from 'admin-on-rest';
import Progress from './Progress';

export const UserList = (props) => (
<List {...props} filters={<PostFilter />}>
    <Datagrid bodyOptions={{ stripedRows: true}}>
        <TextField source="firstName" />
        <TextField source="lastName" />
        <TextField source="email" />
        <TextField source="phone" />
        <TextField source="type" />

//below is the custom column using rc-progress
//the Line component has a property percent that takes an int for example 40
//I tried to pass a variable from the Progress class called progressPercent with by using percent={Progress.progressPercent}

        <FunctionField label="Progress" render= {function render() { return ( <Line percent={Progress.progressPercent} strokeWidth="6" strokeColor="#38bcd5" />);}} />

        <ViewNewHireButton />
    </Datagrid>
</List>
);

export default UserList;
```

I'm getting the error `uncaught at handleFetch TypeError: Cannot read property 'progressPercent' of undefined`

Here is the Progress.js file where I'm calculating a value to pass back to the Line component that renders the progress bar

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

//create Progress class and initiate arrays
class Progress extends Component {
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
        totalTasks: [],
        totalTaskCount: 0,
        progressPercent: 0
    };
}

//make api call, get all tasks from workflow and calculate value for progress percent
componentWillMount(progressPercent) {
    fetch   ('http://localhost:4001/Workflow')
    .then(results => {
        return results.json();
    }).then(data => {

        //get tasks from api and add to array
        let totalTasks = data.results.map((totalTasks) => {
        return(totalTasks.results)
        })

        this.setState({totalTasks: totalTasks});
        console.log("state", this.state.totalTasks);

        //hardcode count of user tasks for now
        let userTaskCount = 1;

        //divide count of user tasks by count total tasks to get progress percent
        let progressPercent = userTaskCount/totalTasks.length;
    })
}

}
```

From all the articles I've read I can't seem to pinpoint how to pass a variable into a datagrid in admin-on-rest from a separate class

I found this article:
[How to access variables inside render in ReactJS from another class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40325791/how-to-access-variables-inside-render-in-reactjs-from-another-class-edit-anoth)
but it's specifically talking about passing it through render which I'm not trying to do I'm just trying to pass the data.

It sounds like [Redux](https://redux.js.org/basics/usage-with-react) would solve these problems by making data globally available but that isn't an option for me right now.

Maybe the whole approach has issues please let me know or if more information is needed let me know too. Thank you!

Comment: Admin-On-Rest uses redux out of the box so if you want to pass info between components then it will have to be through Redux. Also even if you do get this to work the above code will make a fetch call for every single line of your list. Why do you need to make a fetch call in progress bar anyway? AOR has pretty clear ways to make REST calls without having to write fetch in a component

Comment: Thanks yes. I’m very new to admin-on-rest and React. Thanks for the direction.  It looks like I’m forced to store data in Redux which looks daunting but I’ll start on that.  I’ll look at the documentation again on rest api calls and update this question. Thanks for your help!

Comment: AOR (and Redux) is much simpler than it seems the first time you bump into it. I would also suggest writing shorter and more precise questions so it takes people less effort to read deeply and give you a very specific reply.